# PHP combine two tables and list all from first table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to combine two tables.
table A: has multiple posts with unique URL and table B has votes for specific posts from table A.
Now I want to list all rows from table A and if a post has a vote in table B to attach that to one row.
I've tried this, but it excludes the posts who matches the table A with table B. It returns only without any votes.

```
SELECT a.id,a.url,a.content,a.sourcetype,a.width,a.height,a.totalvotes,a.score, b.postid,b.userid,b.votetype
  FROM create_general a
  LEFT JOIN votes b ON a.url=b.postid
  WHERE a.status='1' and a.score > 0 order by a.url desc
  LIMIT 24
```

Comment: It look as though you need to join the two tables using post id LEFT JOIN votes b ON a.id=b.postid

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be nice to know more about the table structure, but you definitely do something wired in your on clause:

```
ON a.url=b.postid
```

This says, that the "url" in "table a" has to be the same than the "postid" in "table b".

Usually a url would look like this: "https://google.de" and a postid is just a number, perhaps "7", so they cannot be the same.

Comment: url = aw43sa2324 and postid is the same. It's just the structure I use.

Comment: It would be a bad idea to join table using string datatype like url or the one shown in the comment above. Use int data type. By the way, is a.totalvotes a real field?